# Visual Studio 2017 not showing SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I have recently installed SSMS 2017 and Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. However, I cannot see an option to create Integration Services projects. Can you please guide me how to proceed.

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: Did you specify the correct workload during install? Alternatively, install SSDT (SQL Data Tools). All instructions are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You need to install SSDT like Nick is writing :) Just add the installation to the instance of the visual studio you already installed.

Answer (score 3):

What @Nick.McDermaid mentioned is true. To eliminate any confusion, during the visual studio installation there is a feature called SQL Server Data Tools; this will not perform a full SSDT installation.

Based on this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017):

> For most users, SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is installed during Visual Studio installation. Installing SSDT using the Visual Studio installer **adds the base SSDT functionality**, so you still need to run the SSDT standalone installer to get AS *(Analysis Services)*, IS *(Integration Services)*, and RS *(Reporting Services)* tools.

*To download SSDT you can follow the link above.*

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me only after I had deinstalled the older versions of Visual Studio for Applications 2014 and 2015 before I updated the ones for 2017 and 2019.